# search library for writing own email app in android

Tags: java, android, email

I am trying to write my own email (imap) app for android plattforms.
There for I search for a library to help me by getting imap-folders and help me by sending emails or getting emails from the server with methods anf classes.

- I looked in the source code of k9 -> its to complex for me.
- I looked in the source code of the official email-app of android -> its to complex for me, but iI had seen the package emailcommon, but without a documentation.
- I find the library javamail, but no documentation for using it with android.

What is the best library for writing an email-app for android?

Answer (score 0):

as I cannot comment so writing as answer.. To me Javamail is a very good one. you can find following links helpful

for android javamail project you can try

http://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/

here is the javamail api doc

http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/index.html

and i found a doc file helpful. can not give the link for limitation. search using javamail doc.

Comment: my problem by using javamail is to store the message objects in a sqlite-database. if i store a message i cant link the stored one with the same message online to change flags, or delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Jakarta Commons Net library works fine: http://nilvec.com/sending-email-without-user-interaction-in-android.html

I used it and for me it's good enough.

Answer (score -2):

I found someone library and I still read the code.

You can check [this one](https://github.com/kristijandraca/BackgroundMailLibrary).